# Javascript ForEach object in bracket array?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have an array that looks like this:

```
{ messages:
   [ { username: 'wef', message: 'f', type: 'chat' },
     { username: 'wef', message: 'we', type: 'chat' },
     { username: 'wef', message: 'wefwefwef', type: 'chat' } ] }
```

How do I loop through all objects in `messages`? I tried doing a for loop but that just sends the array itself and not each object.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You mean, you want to loop thru each property of the object?

Comment: @Eddie — They want to loop through all the objects in the array that is the value of messages.

Comment: "I tried doing a for loop but that just sends the array itself and not each object." — A for loop is fine. We can't tell what you did wrong when you tried to use one because you forgot to include a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

take a look

```
var obj = { messages:
   [ { username: 'wef', message: 'f', type: 'chat' },
     { username: 'wef', message: 'we', type: 'chat' },
     { username: 'wef', message: 'wefwefwef', type: 'chat' } 
]
 }
obj.messages.map(({username, message,type}) => console.log("username, message,type", username, message,type))
```